# MySQL JOIN vs PHP foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, indexing

I'm having a problem optimizing a MySQL Query, but so far it takes too long to pull a simple result limited to 500 records.

My query is this:

```
SELECT ou.*, gr.accepted, gr.value 
FROM offer_usermeta ou 
LEFT JOIN gateway_requests AS gr ON ou.customer_id = gr.customer_id 
WHERE ou.customer_id != "" 
AND ou.created >= '2012-10-08 00:00:00' 
AND ou.created <= '2012-10-08 23:59:59' 
ORDER BY ou.created DESC LIMIT 500
```

This query is taking an entire minute to iterate over maybe 40,000 records. I need it to pull in gateway responses based on the customer ID if there are any and the data looks correct with this query, but I need tips on optimizing. I was considering just pulling the data in separately and foreach'ing it together as necessary, but I know that's probably going to be far slower...

Any tips? (I'm using codeigniter if anyone knows a fancy trick in there as well)

Comment: Please post your tables' structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an index on the `created` column if you haven't so far. The DB will have to fetch all records to do the `order by` and match the `where`  condition no matter if you have a `limit` of only 500 records. After that try

```
SELECT ou.*, gr.accepted, gr.value 
FROM offer_usermeta ou 
LEFT JOIN gateway_requests AS gr ON ou.customer_id = gr.customer_id 
WHERE ou.created between '2012-10-08 00:00:00' and '2012-10-08 23:59:59' 
ORDER BY ou.created DESC 
LIMIT 500
```

Comment: "not is null" gave an error and customer_id is never null.

*EDIT* it's "is not null", errors if it's the other way around.

Comment: it can be `null` in a `left join`. That is why you used `ou.customer_id != ""`, right? And I changed the where clause to `is not null`

Comment: `IS NOT NULL` might not be "correct". If the column is `NOT NULL` that condition is pointless.  It depends on if the column can be `NULL` and what is used for an empty value.  It would help if @ark3typ3 posted the structure of the tables.

Comment: @G-Nugget: You are right. `ou.customer_id` is not on the joined table but on the first one. In that case it can't be null.

Comment: This worked, but after some benchmarking I actually did have faster results with a foreach (3 seconds vs 54 seconds). I'm not sure how that was, but since this is a low traffic feature that only admins and executives will see I'm not too worried about dramatic effects on server performance...I'll keep looking into optimizing my queries though because I feel like a few modifications could have lead to much faster performance with the structure I've implemented

Comment: @ark3typ3: Did you try adding an index on `created`?

Comment: @juergen d: I did and it made a marginal difference in this case (took off 1 second). Do you have a good guide online for MySQL Optimization or any books you'd recommend? I feel like the flaw is in my design and not so much my query at this point.

Comment: See [this](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/MySQL/Optimization). Use can use `explain select ...` to see where your query does not use indexes.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do a between statement, which is more efficient.

AND ou.created between '2012-10-08 00:00:00' AND '2012-10-08 23:59:59'

Comment: Thanks for the tip, it shaved off a second, but it's a lot more readable and friendly so I liked it.